# Building a Proxy for remote sites (cross-origin js)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, proxy, cross-domain

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC Application that requires us to run a Javascript Bookmarklet on a remote website. Because we have a cross-origin security restrictions on the browser and can not load the remote site in an iFrame, We thought about building a "Proxy" of some sort to download the html of the page and load it on our own page and manipulate it as needed. For this we have the below test code that works:

```
    public ActionResult test(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.DownloadData(url));

        // Do manipulation here...

        return Content(html);
    }
```

This simple piece of code works really well with one exception. all the relative links (js, css, image, etc...) obviously doesn't load. We had two questions:

1. Is this the best way of handling this problem? While researching we believe this way we can directly inject the Javascript that we need into be page and we're done.
2. What would be the best way (efficient way) to convert all the relative urls on the downloaded page into absolute urls? (would regEx be a good route to take?)